# 100% width div doesn't display correctly in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Well I have, I think, kind of unusual question. Well I have a web page with starting div with absolute position.

```
.head_warp
{
 width:100%;
 display:block;
 height:238px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
 position:absolute;
 text-align:center;
 background-image:url(images/demo6_fon.png);
 background-position:center;
 background-position:top;
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 z-index:-9999;
}
```

and after that I have a container

```
#container_out
{
 width:1024px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

The HTML is that way:

```
<div class="head_warp"></div>
<div id="container_out"></div>
```

The idea is the content in the "container"  to be shown over the "head_warp" and it's ok in any browser I tested with. Chrome, FF, Safari even with IE8 and IE7. But my co worker is with IE8 with windows VISTA and look what is the result
[alt text http://www.pechat.mdkbg.com/problem.jpg](http://www.pechat.mdkbg.com/problem.jpg)

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

@Puaka I think all browsers are relative to the parent container when specifying a percentage width. In this case it should be relative to the body.

Is your DOCTYPE correct?

If you are absolutely positioning an element, you should be specifying the top/left position which you don't appear to be doing. Also, you specify `margin:0 auto;` implying there could be a left/right margin. I would have thought this should be simply `margin:0;`?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: Yeah, that's OK. Just to add, if the DOCTYPE was omitted or you have content (even empty space) above the DOCTYPE then IE can potentially render the document in quirksmode which can result in your site displaying incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're missing some information for your absolutely-positioned `div`:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

in IE, 100% width will use its parent width, so you need to put it inside container_out, change your container_out css, maybe add padding-top/margin-top = header_warp height

Comment: I thought of that but in the bottom right of the page I have body background witch is part of the design.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested it in IE8 on Vista and it displayed fine.

It looks like all that div is doing is displaying a background image for the page. Why not just add the background image to `body` and get rid of that div?

Comment: I thought of that but in the bottom right of the page I have body background witch is part of the design.